# ggplot2 plot all levels of a group variable in the same tile

Tags: r, ggplot2, tile

I would like to plot each value of "x" for each gene, as well as each level of the three non-exclusive "type" (group variable) it belongs to. 
Is it possible to split the square or tile into the three levels of the group variable, or  show each level next to each other instead of on a different facet as below?

If it were another plot I could use "pairs" and jitter the group variables for example.

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(gene = factor(c(rep('gene1',2), rep('gene2',2), rep('gene2',2), 
rep('gene3',2), rep('gene3',2), rep('gene1',2))),
            x = factor(c(rep('a',3), rep('a',3), rep('b',3), rep('c',3))))
dat$type <- factor(rep(1:3))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(gene, x, fill=type)) + geom_tile() + facet_grid(type ~ .)
```

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for. Perhaps `geom_tile(position="dodge")`?

Comment: Thank you Martin. How do I plot the three "type" for each gene and x next to each other instead of on different fecets?

Answer (score 0):

Am i understanding correct that you want this:

```
    library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(gene, type, fill=type)) + geom_tile() + facet_grid(x~.)
```

Edit: Maybe you need to do a mosaic plot. In that case the "ggmosaic" package might be the solution. It will give you a result that looks something like this:

[image]

```
#To install:
devtools::install_github("haleyjeppson/ggmosaic")

library(ggmosaic)
ggplot(data=dat) + geom_mosaic(aes(x=product(x, gene), fill = type), divider = ddecker())
```

Comment: Thanks Siim, I was wondering though if there is a way to avoid using facet_grid and just use the grouping for example with dodge/jitter

Comment: Martin Gal seems to have given you that answer:

`ggplot(dat, aes(gene, x, fill=type)) + geom_tile(position="dodge")`

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Almost! Thank you! The only part that is missing is that the tiles should all be the the same size (square split into 3 and colored by type). How it comes out now instead, if there is only one type, it takes only the 1/3, while I would like it to take up the entire tile for that gene even if there is 1 value for type. Also, the genes by x don't align (because of this). Maybe adding blanks for the missing?

Comment: I think I am almost there... maybe doing something like filling in all the factor levels but then coloring only by the type: 
library(tidyr); dat2 = merge(dat, data.frame(complete(dat, gene, x, type, fill = list(type=NA))), by=c("gene", "x"), all.y=T); 
ggplot(dat2, aes(gene, x, fill=type.y, color=type.x )) + geom_tile(position="dodge") + scale_fill_discrete(na.value = "white")

Although that still does not work... how to make the "type" plotted but not colored for missing?

Comment: Im still not quite sure i understand what you need, but i think you may be thinking of a mosaic plot? In that case the ggmosaic package might help you. I don't think i can add a picture in the comments here so i will edit my original answer with a picture and you can see if this is what you are thinking of.